# How to send a voice message using flutter?

Tags: flutter

Actually I need to send a voice message to my contacts using flutter.I have searched a lot.But I didn't get any idea on this.Is there any way to do this.?

Comment: Whats to send prerecorded message or record and send?

Comment: I need to send an Instant records.

Comment: Can you please check https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=share+file where many plugins available for sharing files

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Mahadik .But I have checked on that also.Still I didn't get any idea.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to share a voice message in a chat(e.g firebase chat) you can use [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound), send a voice file to your cloud, and you can play it again with flutter_sound too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the audio_recorder package:

https://pub.dev/packages/audio_recorder

```
// Import package
import 'package:audio_recorder/audio_recorder.dart';

// Check permissions before starting
bool hasPermissions = await AudioRecorder.hasPermissions;

// Get the state of the recorder
bool isRecording = await AudioRecorder.isRecording;

// Start recording
await AudioRecorder.start(path: _controller.text, audioOutputFormat: AudioOutputFormat.AAC);

// Stop recording
Recording recording = await AudioRecorder.stop();
print("Path : ${recording.path},  Format : ${recording.audioOutputFormat},  Duration : ${recording.duration},  Extension : ${recording.extension},");
```